# Add a layout in a view

Tags: android, layout, android-canvas

I have this code so I can draw with the finger on a particular image. Now I want to add a Layout and some Imageviews in this Layout. How I can do this?
Because I want to add in the Layout some onTouch and onClick Listeners to can move the ImageViews. 
Also, could I add a existing xml layout or only to create new ones dynamically?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyView view1 =new MyView(this);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    setContentView(view1);
}

public class MyView extends View {

    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.half_court);
      //  this.inflate(c, R.drawable.playera1, null);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    }

    @Override
   protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       // canvas.drawLine(mX, mY, Mx1, My1, mPaint);
       // canvas.drawLine(mX, mY, x, y, mPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);


    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
           // mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
           //   Mx1=(int) event.getX();
             //  My1= (int) event.getY();
               invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

(EDIT) When I try the solution of Gunaseelan, I take this errors:

> 04-09 13:05:08.842: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 50K, 4% free
>   9056K/9347K, paused 89ms 04-09 13:05:08.892: I/dalvikvm-heap(852):
>   Grow heap (frag case) to 11.503MB for 2716016-byte allocation 04-09
>   13:05:09.033: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free
>   11708K/12039K, paused 9ms+19ms 04-09 13:05:09.741:
>   D/AndroidRuntime(852): Shutting down VM 04-09 13:05:09.751:
>   W/dalvikvm(852): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x409c01f8) 04-09 13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 04-09 13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mitsos.thebasic/com.mitsos.thebasic.main}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. 04-09
>   13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>   04-09 13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>   04-09 13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 04-09
>   13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>   04-09 13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-09
>   13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-09 13:05:09.783:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 04-09
>   13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-09
>   13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-09 13:05:09.783:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   04-09 13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 04-09
>   13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-09 13:05:09.783:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(852): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The
>   specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on
>   the child's parent first. 04-09 13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3337) 04-09
>   13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3208) 04-09
>   13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3188) 04-09
>   13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
>   04-09 13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:260)
>   04-09 13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1855) 04-09
>   13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
>   com.mitsos.thebasic.main.onCreate(main.java:53) 04-09 13:05:09.783:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 04-09
>   13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   04-09 13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>   04-09 13:05:09.783: E/AndroidRuntime(852):    ... 11 more 04-09
>   13:05:21.712: I/Process(852): Sending signal. PID: 852 SIG: 9

Comment: you can do it as normal. extend a linearlayout and add your views to it. all the stuffs you wanna do, can be implemented in a standard android layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
layout.addView(iv);
layout.addView(view1);
setContentView(layout);
```

Then your `onCreate()` should be

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyView view1 =new MyView(this);

    LinearLayout layout =  new LinearLayout(this);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
    layout.addView(iv);
    layout.addView(view1);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    setContentView(layout);
}
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do this, my program shuts down with errors. And never runs. Do you want to upload my errors?

Comment: I try it now, I put them last lines on the contsructor of Myview but the same errors appears!
I upload again my errors

Comment: Yes, I think so. But this guy has this line setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
but I use the setContentView(view1);
I think there is the problem but without this line I cannot draw without this